# Git does not add files (nothing to commit)

Tags: git

I tried to clean my git up a bit, so I untracked all files with

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Afterwards, I tried to add them again with

```
git add -A
```

or

```
git add .
```

but, neither of them seem to work, because when I try to commit, it says that there's nothing to commit and the working directory is empty.
I've run those in the root folder, so that should not be the problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Comment: the same (nothing to commit, working directory empty)

Comment: any .gitignore? are you ignoring them?

Comment: I am ignoring some files in the .gitignore, but definitely not all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If after the

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

you do not commit, nothing changes in the repo history. That is why the `add` commands have no effect. (After a rm, you do a `git reset HEAD ...files...` or `git checkout ...files...` to undo the effects of `git rm`, not with `git add`)

Do this:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git commit -m "Untracked everything"
```

Now git add will work:

```
git add -A
```

or

```
git add .
```

Answer (score 1):

you can track again by setting --no-assume-unchaged flag. Try with this command:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged filename
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to return state of your repository to original situation (before `git rm`), do this:

```
git reset       # unstage - undo effect of "git add" or "git rm"
git checkout .  # revert any local changes
```

---

Note that `git rm` followed by `git commit` would not decrease space used by deleted files, so this is not really good way to "clean up".

Instead, you could have simply started from scratch:

```
rm -rf .        # remove everything, including .git directory
git init        # initialize git repository from scratch
```